# Could the center of rotation of a spinning aircraft move away from CG?

Tags: aircraft-design

Picture a barbell shape or twirlers baton spinning.  Perfectly symmetrical.  Rotating at its center of gravity.

Now replace one of the ends with fins of equal mass an spin it again, once in a vacuum, then in air.  Will the centers of rotation be different?  Why?  Could this apply to aircraft?   Thanks.

Comment: In a spinning aircraft, is the axis of rotation even within the aircraft? I would have thought it would be way outside the aircraft.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "center of rotation"? You need to edit your question to explain what you mean by "center of rotation", because clearly you are thinking it means something different from what I think it means. I'm flagging this question as unclear, because until that's explained, the question isn't sufficiently meaningful to be answered.

Comment: Actually in a normal erect spin the center of rotation is offset from the CG slightly.

Comment: In what reference frame?

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, rotation is *rarely* around the centre of mass. It is extremely convenient to *consider* any motion as rotation around CM plus translation of that CM, but it doesn't have to be so.

Take the most basic control input for example: from level flight, you pull up for a short climb. A typical explanation of what happens says that the tail produces a pitch-up moment, which rotates the airplane around its CM to a higher angle of attack, this increases lift and it starts to climb. However, a more detailed analysis will point to the fact that initially, the tail will produce an *extra* negative lift. This is not just a pure moment, this is an unbalanced force applied away from CM. As a result, the airplane will *lose* some of its lift and will start sinking. Only later will lift grow and pull the airplane up.

Now, if you consider it as a single motion (which it is, fundamentally), you can rightfully say that it is a pure rotation about a point *ahead* of CM. (It would be nice to draw a diagram here, but not now). The pilot will perceive it as such. On some designs, particularly with delta wings, this initial loss of lift from elevons is so strong that the virtual point of rotation can be ahead of the aircraft (and thus the cockpit). Space shuttle reportedly had such configuration. For pilots, this creates a weird sensation that the aircraft behaves contrary to the expectation, particularly on landing where perception of altitude is acute. This can lead to pilot-induced oscillations.

So, for *any* motion, not only spin, to say that rotation always *happens* around CM is a simplification. To be able to say that and remain valid, you have to consider all the translation effects as well. In most cases, this is still the easiest way, but if you want to speak of rotation alone, remember that the instantaneous centre of rotation rarely aligns with CM.

Comment: The downforce of the elevator that you speak of here is quite pronounces on long airplanes like the A340. If you don't flare early enough you can pull all you want, the aircraft is not going to pitch up but rather be accelerated down by the elevator downforce.
Same happens on the vertical axis, too. If you apply full rudder the aircraft almost rotates about the cockpit, not around the cm. I love watching that on crosswind landings, the cockpit stays on centerline whilst the rest of the aircraft, including the CM moves left and right :D

Comment: @Jan, the force is even _more_ pronounced on short airplanes. By definition, if you have a shorter arm, you need greater force for the same effect. This is why delta wings are so prominent in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, rotation is always around centre of mass: an unbalanced force causes linear acceleration of centre of gravity and a torque (moment of force) causes angular acceleration (rotation) around centre of mass. This decomposition follows simply from laws of conservation of linear and angular momentum.

However a spin is a combination of spiraling motion and rotation and the centre we talk about here is the centre of that spiralling motion. This centre starts ahead of the aircraft (and to the side, since the spin is to one side of the flight path before stall) and is closer to the aircraft for flatter spins.

Note that this means there is both torque, making the plane rotate, and an unbalanced lateral (centripetal) force, making it turn around.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, when I do a stall spin to the right my body wants to move forward and to the left of the airplane. That would indicate that the center of rotation is right of the center of mass and no longer in the symmetry plane.